# A circle centered at $(4,0)$ is tangent to the curve $y=x^3+1$ at the point $(x_0, y_0)$.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let the sum of all possible values of $x$ be $p/q$, where $p,q$ are relatively prime positive integers. Compute $p+q$.

This problem is somewhat perplexing. Letting $a=x_0$, I got that $$f(a)=3a^5+3a^2+a-4=0.$$ Now by graphing, it is clear that this quintic only has 1 real solution (alternatively, you could take the derivative and notice how sharp it is). The root seems to be around 0.83, and the rational root test fails. At this point I conclude that the problem had a mistake. Given that this problem was on a recent competition, this seems unlikely.

Is there any interpretation of the problem, or any notion of an intended interpretation that would lead to an existing solution?

Comment: The problem itself is problematic. No rational x could be found.

Comment: But what exactly is the question? Your title doesn't mention $p/q$ at all. And the question body doesn't mention either the circle or the cubic. Please clarify.

Comment: Apparently 3 people got credit for this question. I will update with the unknown answer once the solutions come out.